# Java converting for to while loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
 public static Boolean penambahanSaldo(String nama, int saldo){
    for(Penumpang pen : dataPenumpang){
        String temp = pen.getNama();
        if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(nama)){
            pen.tambahSaldo(saldo);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can i convert for loop to while loop,
im so confused right now

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: i need to modify one code for many student in my collage with no similariity
can u helm me to modify the for each to normal for looping?

Comment: Many student will start laugh at you as for not successful professor. Do you still need it?

Comment: ahahaha, im a student too

Comment: What are you studying? Not Java yet. Can you tell me what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Penumpang` is an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) since you are using it in a [`for-each`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) loop, you can retrive the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) using the [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator()) method. Then you can leverage the [`hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--) and [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) methods to consume and iterate over elements

```java
public static Boolean penambahanSaldo(String nama, int saldo) {
  Iterator<Penumpang> iter = dataPenumpang.iterator();

  while (iter) {
    Penumpang pen = iter.next();
    if (pen.getNama().equalsIgnoreCase(nama)) {
      pen.tambadSaldo(saldo);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, can u help me to modify my code? just a litte, im so confused

Comment: dataPenumpang, its an arraylist
ArrayList<Penumpang> dataPenumpang= new ArrayList<>();
its possible to do hasnext?

Comment: Yes, ArrayList inherets from Iterable. I had Iterator and iterable mixed up in my head so I'll update the answer

Comment: or maybe u can change using normal for like for like that(Integer birthday : birthdays) {
   System.out.println(birthday);
}

Comment: can u write the example if using a normal for like that, not for each

Comment: `for(Penumpang pen : bus.getPenumpangBiasa()){
            if(pen.getID() == pp.getID()){
                return true;
            }
        }`

how to convert it to normal for?

Comment: Yes, you'd simply use `dataPenumpang.hasNext()` as the contidion `for (Penumpang pen; penumpangData.hasNext(); pen = dataPenupang.next()) { ... }`. This will use the default constructor for `Penumpang` which creates some (if very minaml) overhead so you are better off using a while loop here